# Circuit to a/b switch like a relay would. So an analog or digital signal can be turned on or off or routed

Tags: transistors, relay, circuit-design, opto-isolator, solid-state-relay

I need to build an arduino-based switcher / router for a multi-arcade to route controls to different game boards, and also switch 2 vga inputs into one output.  Without introducing any lag also.

3 increasinly complex examples of what I need this to do:

First is to take a bunch of leaf switch buttons (which technically are each connecting a pin on a jamma board to ground when pushed) and using arduino to route which pin on 2 different jamma boards is being connected to ground by the button push. It's basically button mapping for different games. I'll have some limited needs in this area but the biggest one is a/b switching between 2 full sets of controls based on what game is being played.

Example 2 is switching 4 pins from the leaf switch buttons to trackball outputs.  Which I think is still taking the lines low to ground but is more of a digital signal than a guy randomly smashing on a button.

Example 3 is a/b switching 2 vga outputs to a single vga output. And the lines in a vga are analog signals.

I'm not an EE so I still think in terms of a relay, which can a/b switch a single line no matter (within reason) what's on it.  So I would expect a relay could pass through any signal in either direction on that line since it's physically connecting the 2 pins together.

What is the digital circuit equivelant of a relay? I was considering optocouplers but that still functions like a transistor, right?  So not any signal could travel through it in either direction.  But maybe something like this would work for examples 1 and 2. Would it introduce any lag?

If I can do parts 1 and 2 I could always buy a vga switcher to do part 3 and hack the switch to still allow arduino to control it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a multi-channel analog switch like the [74AHC4066](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ahc4066.pdf).

Comment: I checkmarked this because after reading the datasheet I believe this will work. I ordered a stack of 4066 ICs.  But it'll be a while before they get here to test.